# Has there ever been a bald-headed Vulcan character in Star Trek?

Tags: star-trek, vulcan

I can't think of one, nor can I find an example online. Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean naturally bald, like Picard?  The priests and healer in the answer below have no hair on their scalps, which may be a grooming choice due to their professions.

Comment: Evolution could have selected for a full head of hair in Vulcan bipeds, as protection against bright sunlight in thin air; it seems to have worked that way for the inner eyelid.  Perhaps Vulcan's sun doesn't produce as much ultraviolet light and cancer risk as ours, though.

Comment: Yes, naturally bald, not shaved bald.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

## Yes, several.

Unnamed Kolinahr Master from *Star Trek: The Motion Picture*:

[image: a bald Vulcan with very large ears wearing a grey robe]

A priest and his attendant from *Star Trek III: The Search for Spock*:

[image: a bald Vulcan wearing a white robe]
[image: a Vulcan wearing a large white hood, his bald scalp barely visible]

And this healer form the *Star Trek: The Animated Series -- "Yesteryear"*:

[image: a bald Vulcan, animated, with a long scraggly white beard wearing a green robe]

[Source](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Unnamed_Vulcans_(23rd_century))

Comment: Holy hannah, those ears!